# Not getting a specified data from get request in json server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, react-redux, json-server

I want specific data while making a GET request from the json server but i am getting an error of undefined. Here is the code for get request.

```
onSubmit={(values) => {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:3001/users/${values.id}`)
      .then((resp) => {
        if (values.email === resp.data.email) {
          console.log(resp.data);
        } else console.log("usereename or pass invalid");
```

and here is the data in my json server

```
 {
  "users": [
    {
      "id": "1afe2286-3e2b-4113-b155-999d7b289f39",
      "email": "zeeshan.naseeb11@gmail.com",
      "password": "112"
    },
    ]}
```

[image: this is the error . kindly hel]

Answer (score -1):

The first argument passed to an `onSubmit` event handler (which you assign to `values`) is the [event object](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html).

It doesn't have an `id` (hence `undefined` appearing in the URL).

You need to get your ID from somewhere it actually exists.

Comment: so my id is in json server how can i get it o onsubmit

Comment: Why are you trying to put the id in the URL if the client doesn't know what it is in the first place?

Comment: basically I'm try to log in the user if the email matches to the email i've given in my json server then push that user to new page. this is what i am trying to achieve. So i am making a get request  to  jason server so i can get the users and apply check on it

Comment: If you want to ask the sever for a user with a specific ID then you **need** to know what ID you want.

Comment: Thanks got your point